# To reduce recovery time (and save space): Is it possible to ignore some PostgreSQL 13 tables (or schemas) when backing up using Barman?

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

We have some large staging/scratch tables in one of our PostgreSQL databases. The data in them can be automatically regenerated from other databases after recovery of the database, and aren't business critical. Is there a way to ignore those tables when backing up using Barman? They are all in one schema.

This is to reduce recovery time and save space.

Maybe we can use some sort of persistent temporary tables? Tablespaces?

We have the tables because it is convenient when we do ETL. But aren't used by any applications or clients.

Are there other alternatives to do something similar?

---

Some documentation I've been reading through:

https://www.pgbarman.org/index.html

http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Barman will create online file system backups, and such backups can only be done of the complete cluster.

To backup parts of a database, you must use a logical backup with `pg_dump`, but then you cannot perform point-in-time recovery.

One way to work around that is to have the tables you don't want to back up be part of a different cluster and access them with `postgres_fdw`, or store them as “flat files” and use `file_fdw` to access them.
Be warned, though, that there are performance penalties when querying such foreign tables.

Comment: Thank you. We used `postgres_fdw` for ETL before, but the amount of data we are working with made it unmanageable. Using `file_fdw` is interesting, didn't know about it. Will have to look into it.

Comment: Turns out last time I tried using `fdw` I set up the target server as a foreign server on the source server. This was a really bad idea. The difference is moving 500k rows in 5 seconds when doing the opposite vs 10000 seconds the way I did previously. For just moving data `fdw` seems really fast. Time will show if we meet significant performance penalties when joining etc. Our fallback will then be to use copy syntax to stdout over the network to a temp table which then does transformations as it inserts.